# Firebase functions :ApiError: Not Found at Object.parseHttpRespBod : when removing from firebase storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm trying to remove an item from my firebase storage by firebase cloud functions.

But its giving me this error..

```
    Error { ApiError: Not Found
    at Object.parseHttpRespBody (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:193:30)
    at Object.handleResp (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:131:18)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/src/util.js:496:12
    at Request.onResponse [as _callback] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:198:7)
    at Request.self.callback (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
  code: 404,
  errors: [ { domain: 'global', reason: 'notFound', message: 'Not Found' } ],
  response: undefined,
  message: 'Not Found' }
```

And this is my code :

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();
var db = admin.firestore();


var storage = admin.storage().bucket('visa_cop');


exports.deletingVisaCop = functions.firestore.document('users/{user_Id}/info/visa_cop').onUpdate((change,context) =>{
    var data = change.after.data().checked;

    if(data === true)
    {
        return storage.delete().then(function(data) {
            return console.log("DataIs",data);
          }).catch(function(error){
             return console.log("Error",error);  
          });
    } else
    {
    }
});
```

And I added for Google APIs Service Agent  and  App Engine default service account storage admin roles from the I am & admin page.

Thank You.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to delete the entire bucket called 'visa_cop'.  Is that what you want?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: iam just trying if it success then i will adjust it later .. but i want to check if it will be deleted or not .. so yes i want to delete all of it

Comment: In that case, the error message is telling you that it couldn't find a bucket with the name you've given.  I will say that creating and deleting buckets programmatically in a Cloud Function is probably not what you really want to be doing.

Comment: i just followed the documentation .. and i have this bucket with its name .. so what is the problem

Answer (score 1):

the problem is here:

```
functions.firestore.document('users/{user_Id}/info/visa_cop').onUpdate((change,context)
```

at the moment, the function listens to a document called "visa_cop" in the folder "info". you need to add the token at the end, to tell the function to listen to update of any file in this folder (or you can specify a file if needed).

Just append e.g. `/{visaId}` after `visa_cop`, like so:

```
functions.firestore.document('users/{user_Id}/info/visa_cop/{visaId}').onUpdate((change,context)
```

Ps. "visaId" can be anything, however it must match the Document Path that you define at function deploy.

in your example, the function listens to any doc in "visa_cop" folder, so if you use:

Console:

- Trigger is "Cloud Firestore"
- Event Type is "update"
- Document Path is "students/{studentId}/visa_cop/{visaId}"

CLI:

```
gcloud functions deploy [FUNCTION_NAME] \
--runtime [RUNTIME] \
--trigger-event providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.update \
--trigger-resource "projects/[PROJECT_ID]/databases/(default)/documents/users/{userId}/info/visa_cop/{visaId}"
```